# divisible modules over Dedekind Domains

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, dedekind-domain

L. Fuchs in one of his articles says that: "*divisible modules over Dedekind Domains can be completely characterized by numerical invariants*". Please introduce me to a source in this respect. I so appreciate any one answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see [*"On Bounded Artinian-Finitary Module "*](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S021819670700386X)?

[image]